# how to uncached schema.json on react native

Tags: react-native, relayjs

I'm using relay with react-native, when I update my graphql schema.json the changes are not detected by my react-native app

I'm getting a validation error `Unknown type myMutationPayload`, but the missing fields are in my localhost:8000/graphql docs

I've checked my schema.json and the fields are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should clear the react-native cache like this:

```
 react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: it does! check here: https://github.com/sibelius/ReactNavigationRelayModern/tree/relay-classic

Comment: `--reset-cache` is not working for me. But manually deleting the `react-native-packager-*` directory under $TMPDIR - does.